# Typescript: How to infer the second parameter Type based on the first one in a typescript generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I have been trying without success on trying to infer the typing of the second generics parameter based on the first one.
Currently I have the following implementation.

```
interface IProps {
  [propertyName: string ]: boolean | number | string
}

class myClass <T extends IProps> {
...
private _map = new Map < keyof T, Array< T[keyof T]>>();
...
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to limit the typings of the array depending on the linked type of the entry of the map.

If I have a

```
{ 
  x:"string",
  y:0
}
```

I would like to restrict my map so that I would only be able to refer to `Array<string>` when calling `_map.get("x")` and only `Array<number>` when calling `_map.get("y")`.

Comment: The property in the class is called `_map` but you want to access `map`. Is that a typo?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using a `Map`, because its values always all have the same static type. You might be able to do it using a mapped type, but you would also need to make `IProps` less general (without the index signature) to make that work.

Comment: The typings for `Map` don't work that way; you'd have to write your own as shown in the answer to the linked question (although I still never quite understand why people reach for `Map` when plain objects already behave this way).

Answer (score 0):

There is no correlation between `keyof T` and `Array<T[keyof T]>`.

Any key from `T` will return any value type from `T`.